# Datanucleus JSON

Tags: json, datanucleus

Looking at the `Datanuclues JSON` code listings, it seems that it supports `Amazon S3` and `Google Storage`, however I believe it is not limited just to these two "JSON" storage, so my question is what qualified to be a JSON storage in respect to the `Datanuclues JSON` library?

I mean, is there any specification for custom "JSON storage" to follow?

Also from the the documentation there is these fields that needs to be set:

```
datanucleus.ConnectionURL=json:http://www.mydomain.com/somepath/
datanucleus.ConnectionUserName=
datanucleus.ConnectionPassword=
```

For the benefit of a custom JSON storage,

- How does Datanucleus pass the `ConnectionUserName` and the
  `ConnectionPassword` to the store?
- The Http response 200, 201, 202, 204, 404 are the only accepted response?
- Putting any kind of JSON record in the `/{primary key}` is allowed? Or what kind of entity is available for persisting?
- Is the 'primary key' here unique for every JSON document being stored in the relative path like `/Person/{primary key}`, primary key is unique?

Also, I'm not quite understanding clearly the JDO config:

- Is the `key="url"` the `/{primary key(url?)}`? or its something else like: `http://myapp.com/someurl/Person/{primary key}`?